# Running an app error [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android

I am trying to run an App on Android Studio. I plugged in my Droid X and ran the App. I get this as an error " [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] ". My App works on a virtual simulator. Please help.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, check to make sure that the android:minSdkVersion="##" line has a SDK number of less than that running on your Droid X. Most likely your virtual simulator has a higher SDK number than what is listed in your manifest and your Droid X has a lower SDK number than in your manifest

Comment: I can't find the SDK # in my manifest

Comment: You should have a <uses-sdk segment which contains the android:minSdkVersion line in it (among an <application segment)